# SQL Server partition and index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to design a table that is going to have around 80 million records. I created a partition for every month using persisted column (if its wrong suggest me the best way). Please find below scripts that I used to create tables and partition and the query that's going to be used often. Only Insertion and deletion will be done on this table.

```
-- Create the Partition Function 
   CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Invoice_item (int)
   AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

-- Create the Partition Scheme
   CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_Invoice_item
   AS PARTITION PF_Invoice_item ALL TO ([Primary]);



   CREATE TABLE [Invoice]
   (
   [invoice_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [Invoice_Number] [varchar](255) NULL,
   [Invoice_Date] [date] NULL,
   [Invoice_Total] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
   [Outstanding_Balance] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([invoice_id] ASC)
   )



  CREATE TABLE [InvoiceItem](
  [invoice_item_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [invoice_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [invoice_Date] [date] NULL,
  [make] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [serial_number] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [asset_id] [varchar](100) NULL,
  [application] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [customer] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [ucid] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [dcn] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [dcn_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [device_serial_number] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [subscription_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [product_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [subscription_start_date] [date] NULL,
  [subscription_end_date] [date] NULL,
  [duration] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [promo_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
  [promo_end_date] [date] NULL,
  [discount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
  [tax] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
  [line_item_total] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
  [mth]  AS (datepart(month,[invoice_date])) PERSISTED NOT NULL,**
  [RELATED_PRODUCT_RATEPLAN_NAME] [varchar](250) NULL,
  [SUB_TOTAL] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
  [BILLING_START_DATE] [date] NULL,`enter code here`
  [BILLING_END_DATE] [date] NULL,
  [SUBSCRIPTION_ID] [varchar](200) NULL,
  [DEVICE_TYPE] [varchar](200) NULL,
  [BASE_OR_PROMO] [varchar](200) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceItem_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([invoice_item_id] 
  ASC,[mth] ASC))
  ON PS_Invoice_item(mth);
  GO



 ALTER TABLE [InvoiceItem]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Invoice_ID] 
 FOREIGN KEY([invoice_id])
 REFERENCES [Invoice] ([invoice_id])
```

GO

I will be using below queries

```
select subscription_name,duration,start_date,end_date,promotion_name,
promotion_end_date,sub_total,discount,tax,line_item_total from InvoiceItem 
lt inner join Invoice on lt.invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id where 
invoice.invoice_number='' and lt.customer='' and lt.ucid='' lt.make='' and 
lt.SERIAL_NUMBER='' and lt.dcn='' and lt.application=''

select customer,make,application from billing.AssetApplicationTotals 
lineItem inner join billing.Invoice invoice on 
lineItem.invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id where invoice.invoice_number='';

SELECT  [invoice_Date],[make],[serial_number],[application],[customer],
[ucid],[dcn],[dcn_name],[device_serial_number]
,[subscription_name],[product_name],[subscription_start_date],
[subscription_end_date],[duration],[promo_name],[promo_end_date]
FROM [InvoiceItem] where [application]=''

SELECT  [invoice_Date],[make],[serial_number],[application],[customer],
[ucid],[dcn],[dcn_name],[device_serial_number]
,[subscription_name],[product_name],[subscription_start_date],
[subscription_end_date],[duration],[promo_name],[promo_end_date]
FROM [InvoiceItem] where [customer]=''
```

What is the best way to create index? Shall I create separate non clustered index for each filter, or shall I have Composite index and shall I have covering index to avoid key lookup?

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by partitioning the table?

Comment: @alroc, we will be having around 80 Million records in the table data retrieval should be fast.

Comment: Why do you believe that partitioning the table will improve the performance of your `select` queries? See https://littlekendra.com/2016/05/03/why-table-partitioning-doesnt-speed-up-query-performance-video/

Comment: Searches will be done based on month, it directly searches that particular partition instead of all partition.

Comment: But none of your example queries have month, which suggests that your partitioning will just make things worse

Comment: NB: Looks like you may be missing an `and`: `and lt.ucid='' lt.make=''`